# Why do I get incorrect line breaks in my source code?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, browser, editor

I'm encountering a weird problem with how a php file's code (read: source code) is rendered in some browser's source code view (I've tested Firefox 4, Chrome 10, IE9).

So basically I use Wordpress to show a category, hence using the category.php. The process then would be to copy the output source code into a new .html file and use that as an email newsletter. This has worked wonderfully the last 10 instances, but this time the browser (as stated above, basically *any* browser) messes with the source code as in omitting line breaks (not `<br />`s, but 'new lines' in the code itself, inserting line breaks at other points (for example right between an object and its attribute), and in doing so messes the whole code up. The page still renders okay, but as I need the source code this is a *bit* of a problem for me.

#### Examples

Original code in .php file:

```
<table width="758" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr height="256">
        <td colspan="27" height="256">
            <a href="http://www.motoscoot.es/shop/" target="_blank" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;">
                <img src="https://www.motoscoot.es/img/newsletter/MsNewsletter_top4.gif" alt="Motoscoot.es Novedades" width="758" height="256" longdesc="Motoscoot.es Novedades" border="0" style="border:none;">
            </a>
        </td>



<!-- ...and so on -->
```

Processed Source Code:

```
<table
width="758" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"
bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><tr
height="256"><td
colspan="27" height="256"> <a
href="http://www.motoscoot.es/shop/" target="_blank" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;"><img
src="https://www.motoscoot.es/img/newsletter/MsNewsletter_top4.gif" alt="Motoscoot.es Novedades" width="758" height="256" longdesc="Motoscoot.es Novedades" border="0"
style="border:none;"></a></td></tr><tr
id="main_content_row"><td


<!-- ...and so on -->
```

I can't give you an online link right now as this is all still happening on localhost.

So with the smooshed output code I can of course create the html site, because as I said before, the rendering still works fine. But to really be able to work with it, that's just plain impossible. At first I thought it might be an editor error. I usually work with Dreamweaver, so I tried editing and saving the .php in UltraEdit and in Notepad++, both yielding the same result though.

How do I solve this mess?

Answer (score 0):

Run the HTML through [HTML Tidy](http://infohound.net/tidy/) before you try to edit it. You can also [download your own copy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) if you want to run it from a batch script or something like that.

Comment: Oh I've tried HTML Tidy, this is actually where the whole problem started (once I save the file with the tidied up code, the "smooshing" began). So I'm a bit cautious right there. Though it's a valid solution, I'd try to not add this extra-step, but get rid of the cause in the first place :)

Comment: OK. I misunderstood. So you're trying to edit the HTML, then look at in a browser, then view source and save it and use that as new HTML to edit? Something is not right with your workflow :)

Comment: I'd like to think of it as a perfectly sound, if maybe somewhat insane workflow :) The reason I'm doing it this way is I need the content generated from Wordpress (which isn't a straight html, i.e. I can't attach or send it anywhere), but need to have it as an html file to be able to send it as an email. The copying of the source code into an html file has basically the same effect as saving the rendered Wordpress category as a file with your browser. If you know of an easier way for WP->.html conversion, do tell :) But either way, the code I'm getting is just a huge pile of... messy... mess.